# Small open air space surrounded by a building

Tags: single-word-requests

"In architecture, an atrium (plural: atria or atriums) is a large open air or skylight covered space surrounded by a building."

"Skylight = an opening in a roof or ceiling, fitted with glass, for admitting daylight"

How would you call very small open space inside the building which purpose is to provide some skylight?

(Note: it's open so it doesn't fit well into definition of skylight, while it is small so it doesn't fit well into the definition of atrium).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a *skylight* can be glass or open (as in the Pantheon):

[image]

Secondly, a skylight is only the opening/window itself, not the space/area below. So are you looking for a name for the opening, or for the space below (possibly including the opening)?

You may be looking for the term **light well** or **air shaft**, which is a narrow, high shaft built to allow light to enter from the top (the sun) and illuminate rooms adjacent to it:

[image]

An *atrium* is normally a larger area or hall, mostly covered by a roof or ceiling, with light coming in from a skylight/opening:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the name of a space below including the opening. It seems "lightwell, light well and air shaft" are it. Many thanks

Comment: @MladenAdamovic: Yes, that sounds appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

***Patio*** - a roofless inner courtyard open to the sky (from Spanish, OED).